# Linq to entities query optimizing

Tags: c#, optimization, linq-to-entities

I have 3 tables in my DB which I'm working with:

1. `Theme [Theme_ID]`
2. `ThemeWorkplace [Theme_ID, Workplace_ID, ThemeWorkplace_ID]`
3. `UserTheme [User_ID, Theme_ID, UserTheme_ID, UserTheme_AccessType]`

I need to change `UserTheme_AccessType` for all `UserTheme.Theme_ID` in current workplace with `ThemeWorkplace.Workplace_ID = 2` and current user with `User_ID = 1`. If theme is no row in `UserTheme` for such user and such theme - I need to create it.

I wrote such a code, but it works too long time:

```
var themeList = (from t in m_Entities.Theme
                    where (from tw in m_Entities.ThemeWorkplace
                        where tw.Workplace.Workplace_ID == 2
                        select tw.Theme.Theme_ID).Contains(t.Theme_ID)
                            select t)
                .ToList();

foreach (Theme theme in themeList)
{
    var oldUserTheme = GetByUserTheme(user/*user is given*/, theme);

    if (oldUserTheme == null)
    {
        /* create new User Theme with params, that I need*/
        this.Add(newUserTheme, true);
    }
    else
    {
        /* here - changing found row */
        oldUserTheme.UserTheme_AccessType = 2;
    }
}
```

I understand that this code accesses the database too many times. I want to find a way to get rid of:

```
var oldUserTheme = GetByUserTheme(user/*user is given*/, theme);
```

In every `foreach` iteration. Could somebody please help me?

Adding code of GetByUserTheme():

```
private UserTheme GetByUserTheme(User user, Theme theme)
{
    return m_Entities.UserTheme.FirstOrDefault(ut => ut.User.User_ID == user.User_ID && ut.Theme.Theme_ID == theme.Theme_ID);
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to post the details of how `GetByUserTheme` works.

Comment: Thank you, I've added GetByUserTheme statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: All changes for entities that you have done in code will be pushed to database in one batch command when you call `context.SaveChanges`. So you will have one request to Database for select and one request for update.

But in your batch command will be many sql queries for cause EF generate sql for updates entities one by one (not all in one).

If you want update really many records in database, you should use sql script (call stored procedure or execute sqlquery) against using EntityFramework.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I think it is better for me to study Entity freamework to understand how it all works deep inside.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm completely understanding your question and structure. But based on what I see, could this be a reasonable slution?

First you select the workplaces that have ID equal to 2. From that result you select the theme-ID's. All your userthemes that have a themeID that occurs in the former result will then be selected into 'userThemes'. From there, you iterate over the results and if the userID is empty you create a new UserTheme, otherwise you update it.

*Quick note:* the code below is no real working code. It's just code I wrote to exemplify my explanation, kind of pseudo-code if you will.. :)

```
var userThemes = entities.Userthemes
                         .Where(ut => entities.Workplaces
                                              .Where(w => w.WorkPlaceID == 2)
                                              .Select(s => s.ThemeID)
                                              .Contains(ut.ThemeID));

foreach (UserTheme ut in userThemes)
{
    if (ut.UserID.ToString() == "")
    {
        //Create
    }
    else
        ut.UserThemeAccessType = 2;
}
```